# .htacess redireciona para url errada

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Eu tinha implantando o url amigável em um projeto para testar, daí resolvi implantar no TCC, porém está acontecendo alguma coisa que não consigo detectar o que é. Quando carrego o site em `/` ele abre o `sign-in.php` de boa, o negócio está quando redireciona, o form tem na action `verificaLogin`, porém ele carrega na url todo o caminho junto com a extensão. E nessa `verificalogin.php` caso dê errado, ele deverá voltar para `sign-in.php`, e volta, porém carrega na url `index.php`, coisa que eu não queria. E caso dê certo, ele deveria ir para `pag_Contratos`, essa página está em `view`, porém está carregando `/model/pag_Contratos`, e deveria carregar apenas `pag_Contratos` e com o caminho certo. E caso eu digite uma url errada, ele vai para a página de erro 404, e quando eu clico em retornar para a página principal, ele vai para carrega `home`, sendo que coloquei para carregar `sign-in`. Como disse, usei isso de outro projeto, será que tem algo a ver? Mesmo mudando os links?

Códigos:

.htaccess (está na raiz)

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

index.php (está na raiz)

```
$home = 'view/sign-in';
$url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : $home;
if ($url != $home) {
    $dir = 'view/';
    $url = array_filter(explode('/', $url));
    $url = $dir. $url[0] . '.php'; 
}
// var_dump($url);
echo $url;
if (file_exists($url)) {
    include_once $url;
} else {
    include_once 'view/404.php';
}
```

sign-in.php (está em view):

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="verificaLogin">
<h1 class="h1-large">Login</h1>
<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Endereço de E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="txtu" maxlength="50" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome de Usuário"/>
<br>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
<input type="password" name="txts" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha">
<br>

<div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label class="p-small">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Lembrar minha senha
    </label>
</div>

<br>
</form>
```

verificaLogin.php (está em model):

```
require_once 'conexao.php';
require_once 'banco-login.php';
require_once 'banco-chamado.php';

if ($_POST) {
$user = $_POST['txtu'];
$senha = $_POST['txts'];
session_start();

if (efetuarLogin($conexao, $user, $senha)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $user;
    $cpf = pegaCpfUsuarioLogado($conexao, $user);
    $_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] = pegaTipoUsuario($conexao, $cpf);
    mysqli_close($conexao);
    if ($_SESSION['tipoUsuario'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativo';
        header("location: pag_contratosCli");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'ativoTecnico';
        header("location: pag_contratosTec");
    }
} else {
    echo '<script> var r = confirm("Senha ou usuário incorreto!")
                        if (r === true) {
                            window.location.assign("sign-in");                   
                        } else {
                            window.location.assign("sign-in");
                        }
                        </script>';
}
}
```

404.php (está em view)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>404</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Página não encontrada</h1>
        <a href="sign-in">Retornar a Home</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sugiro começar a pensar em usar um framework JS para gerenciar o sua SPA, recomendo o Vue (mais simples, se você não manja muito de front) ou Angular (mais completo, se você já tem mais ou menos uma noção do que está fazendo). Fazer esse gerenciamento no back costuma ser mais complicado e custoso (performance)